# ReactJS error unhandled Rejection - How to access json file with multiple sections?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

Am following a tutorial on using Fetch with ReactJS, am able to access a certain section of data from the API/json, but when attempting to access other sections, I get an error. this is the JSON file, which is using the following API: https://api.myjson.com/file1

**the code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from "react-dom";
import './BuildingSimulation.css';

class BuildingSimulation extends Component {

    state = { data: [] }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/zb5kf', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiR3JlZyIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZ2dyYWZmIiwibmJmIjoxNTI0ODM5Nzc1LCJleHAiOjE1MjQ5MjYxNzV9.xhvdfaWkLVZ_HLwYQuPet_2vlxNF7AoYgX-XRufiOj0'
            },
        }


        ) /*end fetch */
        .then(results => results.json()) 
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))   
      }


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (

                     <div className="clientContainer">
                            {
                                this.state.data.map( item =>( 
                                <div>
                                    <span> {item.clientName} </span>

                                </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div> 
        );
      }
}

export default BuildingSimulation;
```

...so I'm able to get information from the Segments section to display in the page, but how do I also get the ID in the header of the json file and data from the totals section to display in my page as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing only `segment` data from the API response. To access the other data you need to store the entire reponse inside the `state`. So change

```
.then(data => this.setState({ data: data.segments }))
```

to

```
.then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
```

Now you can access all the response data.

Update:
After doing this, the `this.state.data` represent the json data. So to access `segments`, use `this.state.data.segments`. To access `totals`, use `this.state.data.totals` and so on.

Comment: I thought the same thing, I tried that prior to posting my code, and I get the error: this.state.data.map is not a function. I edited the posted code to reflect what I had first attempted. please let me know if you have other suggestions, thanks

Comment: Prakash Sharma - I had tried what you suggested, but I still get the same error; I modified the code above, could you take a look please and let know what I may be doing wrong. I use the same code for other json files and it works fine. let me know please if you have any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can also burst the object like this:

```
state = {
    id = '',
    segments: [],
    totals: []
}
```

And on the after fetch do like this:

```
.then(results => results.json()) 
.then(({
    id = '',
    segments = [],
    totals = []
}) => this.setState({
    id,
    segments,
    totals
}));
```

Finally, on your render use the state data like this:

```
render() {
    const {
        id,
        segments,
        totals
    } = this.state;

    return (
        <p>ID: {id}</p>
        <ul>
            {
                segments.map((segment) => <EachSegmentComponent segment={segment} />)
            }
        </ul>
        <ul>
            {
                totals.map((total) => <EachTotalComponent total={total} />)
            }
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am on the right path, but I get an error: Failed to Compile -EachSegmentComponet is not defined, the same for EachTotalComponet. ...any suggestions?

Comment: I modified the above code, please let me know if you have any other suggestions

Comment: Yeah you need to create those components too like this: `const EachSegmentComponent = props => <li>{props.key1} {props.key2}</li>`. Sorry I don't know what keys are there on each segment. Similarly you also need to create `EachTotalComponent`. Let me know if you need a fiddle example, I can do that.